# TypeError: a.default.detectStore(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Anyone come across this problem and have general idea or fix of what you did to resolve this.
I just need a nudge in the right direction.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Even **with** the code in the image, it's not at all clear what `a.default` is or why you're assuming it's not `undefined` when, apparently, it is. What steps have you take to debug the fact that `a.default` is `undefined` when you don't expect it to be? What did you find?

Comment: I actually ended up solving the problem. When i clicked on the location of the problem I inspected the code and it had a link to the Paypal Honey website. So I have the firefox extension Honey installed (the one used to get discounts on stuff when you do online shopping) and thought maybe ill just try removing this extension. Maybe its somehow effecting it. So removed it and error gone.... no idea how but hey it works.

Comment: Thanks! Never would have thought it was the Honey extension! These type of errors are so useless and unhelpful. Also using firefox, working on a dotnet core6 application. Error prevented me from logging into my own application! You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Make sure you have an H! tag on the page. That fixed it for me

Comment: @Brad, what do you mean by a H! tag ?

Comment: @xtra Sorry, meant H1

Comment: @keanu.b, you should mark the honey extension as the answer and select it, this solved the issue for me as well.